# Separation of Css files in Rails (makes slow)

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, structure, directory

The logic behind assets folder in rails to make it faster as soon as I understood. However, my app works slow. I think I am doing something wrong.

So, I have css files and js files in assets folders. But some of them are just for 1 pages. But all the files are loaded. I guess because of the `application.js` has

```
//= require_tree .
```

Or the same for css. In this case, whatever the page I click all the css and js files are loaded. Here is the hierarchy of the folders;

[image]

here is whats loaded;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign up | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/account_activations-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/boats-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/carousel-956151185eb5b53745598c8940f18077.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom-77b5d56b10f05640161b7c57eb235662.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/main-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/password_resets-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/profiles-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/sessions-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/users-64e62ddc273c2f5847f30d698ca14b67.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-cd159239290bb1f8647f0f7d39aa3ffc.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-e27bd20a10d28155845a22d71ef94f2f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks-d9dcd5206ee131f11181e8ca09537148.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix-4aa497ad1a679d7fa3de7aa10db2c248.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert-f0634df255bb1dc37f98c8be82434bec.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button-1189204cf501fc7ddbe0384f5c7a3e04.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel-65843039ab1c8b32832fda680448146a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse-4d358a4cbe9ca0a9cc3e124610787f88.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown-a234ed5390532f267df4f5a13236de95.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab-54d92c1012635a68526fcf2590679f4a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition-8cd2695d7ee2b30315b7e024422eb427.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy-5e0c86e7fbc3752c3898df3c690e52fb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal-b75feab289989a62ead5720c2b655fca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip-5a9f4a24a67c380028b0164a546de5f4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover-9666a38e5d68a25bd4e839bee36f5d30.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets-3ca152e549e0b8086e1891275d70a987.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/account_activations-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/boats-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/main-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/password_resets-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/profiles-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/users-fcec5b5a277ac7c20cc9f45a209a3bcd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-1864dbf2e5658f9c8b55e81bcaaf8de2.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="lRaTLkwxRWtgHZP3j1YyWpvkZoo09sR6R4WadYcI+g3I1JHsA3d64FPpW1a76heApiM6FnNRgnueX9aAX2pBNw==" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

Sorry for the long post, is there a way to reorganize everything, so any of them works with its related page?. Thanks

Comment: are you in development environment?

Comment: Yes it is on the  development env yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct that due to `//= require_tree .` all the `js` files are loaded and this is what rails does. But you are currently in development environment which shows each file separately. And yes it affects the speed but to make it faster what rails does that in production mode it compiles all the files into one (css and js files). You can read more about this here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

And an advice is to delete all the blank css and js files. I mean that while you generate a resource, controller or scaffold then it creates a css and js file of same. So if it is not in use then delete it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, did not know it also creates css for generating controller i ll organize it. Appreciated!.